# how to fire event of button in table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<table style="width: 5%;" class="pagination" id="paging">
    <tfoot>
        <td>
            <span>1</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="edit" value="2"> 
        </td>   
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I want to fire click event of button using jQuery and I also want to get value of it.

Comment: Create a click handler to read the value, and use `click()` elsewhere to trigger the click event. See http://learn.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option almost identical to the others, but a bit more complete:

Change

```
<input type="button" name="edit" value="2">
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="edit" value="2" id="MyButtonID">
```

Then attach a function to it like mentioned by others:

```
$(function() {
   $("#MyButtonID").click( function()
      {
          // Do something, like pop a message
          alert("It works!");
      }
   );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work however I would suggest a class on the button to better identify it:

```
$('table').on('click','input[type=button]',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Note that I also isolate to the "button" type here in case you have other inputs in the table somewhere.

Note: IF you only want the value outside the click handler you can use:

```
var buttonValue = $('table').find('input[type=button]').val();
```

Using the class on the table selector:

```
$('table.pagination').on('click','input[type=button]',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Even MORE specific, use the table ID

```
$('#paging').on('click','input[type=button]',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I like the specificity, but why limit it to the table only, and not address it with the class name directly?

Comment: I can do that also ..adding that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get button's value.

```
$("#edit").click(function(){
var editvalue=$("#edit").val();

    alert(editvalue); //shows value on a messagebox

});
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qnST/2/).

Comment: There is no element '#edit' in the OP's example, and why not use `$(this)` for the value?

Comment: i'm assuming input has an id. therefore i created an example in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#button").click( function()
       {
         alert('button '+$(this).attr('id')+' with text '+$(this).text()+' clicked');
       }
  );
});
```

Comment: There is no element '#button' in the OP's example - and your example does not get the "value" as requested